# How do I execute a stored procedure with multiple output parameters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure with 2 output parameters and want to execute it using SQL but fail to get the values out when assigning them to the result of a stored procedure.

In short I have a stored procedure that gets the company of the logged in user that has two output parameters. One is an integer error code and another is the company name. Also the stored procedure returns a result of all the other users of the company.

Since all the users will have the same company name I didn’t want to bloat the response with another field and thought it best to assign company name to a variable but cannot get it to work proper.

My SQL to execute my stored procedure is:

```
DECLARE @parmRET1 VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @parmRET2 int

EXECUTE CRUD_User @pvchAction = 'select',    
                  @Id = '30862982-E189-4CE6-A299-5996D62DDCD5',
                  @pCompanyNameOut = @parmRET1 OUTPUT, 
                  @pIntErrDescOut = @parmRET2 OUTPUT

SELECT @parmRET1 AS [output parameter], @parmRET2 AS [output parameter]
```

My stored procedure code is:

```
alter PROC [dbo].[CRUD_User]
(        
    @Id                 varchar(400)=null,  
    @Name               varchar(400)=null,  
    @Phone              varchar(200)=null,  
    @PriceNotes         varchar(max)=null,  
    @isActive           bit= 0,  
    @pvchAction         varchar(50)=null,        
    @pIntErrDescOut     int output,
    @pCompanyNameOut    varchar(200) output
    )        
AS        
    BEGIN        

    if(@pvchAction='select')        
         begin
                --EXEC    @pCompanyNameOut = dbo.sel_Company_by_UserId @Id OUTPUT

                SET @pIntErrDescOut = '3'; --works in getting output
                EXEC @pCompanyNameOut = sel_Company_by_UserId @Id --not working


                SELECT   *
                FROM   aspnet_Users u
                left outer join UserInfo ui on u.UserId = ui.userId 
                left outer join aspnet_Membership m on m.UserId = u.UserId 
                left outer join Company c on c.Id = ui.CompanyId 
                WHERE u.UserId = isnull(@Id, u.UserId)  ;

                RETURN 

         end
     .....

 IF (@@ERROR <> 0)         
          BEGIN         
                SET @pIntErrDescOut = 1      
          END        
     ELSE        
          BEGIN        
                SET @pIntErrDescOut = 0    
          END    

END
```

when extracting the stored proc sql from sel_Company_by_UserId everything works:

```
SET @pCompanyNameOut = (select Name 
                        from Company C inner join UserInfo ui 
                        on C.Id = ui.CompanyId 
                      where ui.userId = '30862982-E189-4CE6-A299-5996D62DDCD5'  )
```

but fails when i want to have a proc return the same:

```
"EXEC @pCompanyNameOut = sel_Company_by_UserId '30862982-E189-4CE6-A299-5996D62DDCD5'
```

Comment: What is `sel_Company_by_UserId`?  A function?  Another stored procedure?

Comment: yes it is ms sql server, and that is a stored proc

Comment: Is `@pCompanyNameOut ` an output parameter or return value in `sel_Company_by_UserId`?

Comment: This procedure doesnt make much sense you current code says check for  if `@pvchAction='select'` execute the code inside the `BEGIN..END` block and RETURN. Your code never gets to the @@ERROR function section. Also if you have any line to code executing after and error has occurred @@ERROR will reset its value to null.

Comment: i am able to execute the proc via code provided, and it runs the part in the select section, but fails to provide a value to @pCompanyNameOut - how can i get an assignment of comapny to this param?

Comment: when you execute `sel_Company_by_UserId` procedure on its own does it return any value? passing the same GUID value.

Comment: Gotcha You are trying to return a varchar value from your `sel_Company_by_UserId` procedure, you need to use OUTPUT parameter there. A stored Procedure can only RETURN an integer value no other datatype. When you say it fails I think you are getting an error something like "conversion to int failed bla bla..." am I right ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having this little chat in comments section it all boils down to your return value from procedure `sel_Company_by_UserId`, You cannot return anyother datatype other than INT from a procedure. For other than INT datatypes you need to use OUTPUT parameters.

Have a look at the following code.

```
ALTER sel_Company_by_UserId
@Id GUID,
@NameVal VARCHAR(100) OUTPUT   --<-- add this param here with "OUTPUT" key word
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  select @NameVal   =  Name 
  from Company C inner join UserInfo ui 
  on C.Id = ui.CompanyId 
  where ui.userId = @Id
END
```

Now once you have changes the logic inside your `sel_Company_by_UserId` Stored Procedure ,
now change accordingly in `[dbo].[CRUD_User]`.

Something like

```
  if(@pvchAction='select')        
         begin

            SET @pIntErrDescOut = '3'; --works in getting output
            EXECUTE sel_Company_by_UserId @id = @Id
                                        , @NameVal = @pCompanyNameOut OUTPUT 

   ..... rest of your code......
```